# Tab Bar Item won't show

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Currently I have 1 tab view controller, with 3 menus:

[image]

But when running, the bottom menu / image are like being cutted or didn't show perfectly like this:

[image]

[image]

It should have 3 menus.

Code:

```
import UIKit
class TabBarReimbursementViewController: UITabBarController{

    var loadTable: Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.viewControllers![selectedIndex].viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(TabBarReimbursementViewController.buttonClicked(_:)))

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

        //       UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor() ], forState: .Normal)

        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor() ], forState: .Selected)

        let historySelected: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "history2.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        let approvalSelected: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "approve2.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        let listSelected: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "listlist2.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

        (tabBar.items![1] ).selectedImage = historySelected
        (tabBar.items![0] ).selectedImage = approvalSelected
        (tabBar.items![2] ).selectedImage = listSelected

        self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers![1]
        self.findHamburguerViewController()?.gestureEnabled = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyRequestForm") as! myRequestForm
        nextViewController.formType = "New"
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean constraint in the tab bar controller or in the menu ?

Comment: pls check my picture, i added some. i think i didnt use constraint

Comment: Tab bar only works with navigation controller. You cannot directly join the tabbar controller to another view controller. You must embed sub view controllers in navigation controller and than try again.

Answer (score 2):

You CAPSPageMenu Library in which you can use tab bar controller very easily [CAPSPageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)

just add below code in Library

```
    _menuScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _menuScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.width- _menuHeight,self.view.frame.size.width, _menuHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that what you are doing is not how a tab bar controller's tab bar items work. Each child view controller (there are three of them in your storyboard screen shot) has *its own* [`tabBarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621175-tabbaritem), and that is how the tab bar gets populated.